# Custom Auto-Generated Sequences with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an `Employee` table with an employee ID column `EmpID (nvarchar(5))`.

This is how I insert data into the `Employee` table

```
 Employee obj = new Employee();
 obj.EmpID = ?
 DBContext.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
 DBContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I want to make `EmpID`'s value to

```
00001  
00002  
00003  
00004  
....
....
```

How can I create such a custom auto-generated sequence likes this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to let SQL Server handle the auto-incrementing part by using an `INT IDENTITY` column. Don't do this in your C# code - that's a database task.

For your second column that you want to have in a specific, formatted fashion, use a **computed column** based on that identity column.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 EmpID AS RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED, 

 .... your other columns here.......
)
```

That way, when you insert rows into the table, you'll get:

```
ID    EmpID
---------------
 1    00001
 2    00002
........
17    00017
18    00018
......
78    00078
```

The `ID` column is your actual primary and clustering key, it's small, fast, never changes - perfect for a clustering key. And your column `EmpID` is always automatically generated from the `ID` and shows the value in the formatted fashion as you wanted.

**Update :** as @ta.speot.is rightfully commented: if you don't need that `EmpID` value in the database for anything, then the best approach would be to just have the `ID INT IDENTITY` column in the database, and handle the generating of the `EmpID` in your C# code in the `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public string EmpID 
   { 
      get { return "0000" + ID.ToString();  }  // do whatever you need to do here!
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens when `ID` can't be represented by `VARCHAR(5)`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: good point - then you'll get `0000*` in your `EmpID`

Comment: Looking at what OP is using (Entity Framework?) it's probably better just to have `ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)` (i.e. standard EF `Id` column) without the computed column and then put `[NotMapped] public string EmpID { get { ... } }` into `Employee`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: if that value isn't needed in the database - then yes, that would be the easiest way to go.